# Is memcpy the standard way to pack float into uint32?

Tags: c++, process, type-conversion, memcpy

Is the following the best way to pack a float's bits into a uint32?  This might be a fast and easy yes, but I want to make sure there's no better way, or that exchanging the value between processes doesn't introduce a weird wrinkle.

"Best" in my case, is that it won't ever break on a compliant C++ compiler (given the static assert), can be packed and unpacked between two processes on the same computer, and is as fast as copying a uint32 into another uint32.

**Process A:**

```
static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32) && alignof(float) == alignof(uint32), "no");
...

float f = 0.5f;
uint32 buffer[128];

memcpy(buffer + 41, &f, sizeof(uint32)); // packing
```

**Process B:**

```
uint32 * buffer = thisUint32Is_ReadFromProcessA(); // reads "buffer" from process A
...

memcpy(&f, buffer + 41, sizeof(uint32)); // unpacking

assert(f == 0.5f);
```

Comment: You might be interested in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qzMpk-22cc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the standard way to do type punning.  Cppreferences's page on [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) even includes an example showing how you can use it to reinterpret a `double` as an `int64_t`

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <cstdint>
> #include <cstring>
>
> int main()
> {
>     // simple usage
>     char source[] = "once upon a midnight dreary...", dest[4];
>     std::memcpy(dest, source, sizeof dest);
>     for (char c : dest)
>         std::cout << c << '\n';  
>     // reinterpreting
>     double d = 0.1;
> //  std::int64_t n = *reinterpret_cast<std::int64_t*>(&d); // aliasing violation
>     std::int64_t n;
>     std::memcpy(&n, &d, sizeof d); // OK     
>     std::cout << std::hexfloat << d << " is " << std::hex << n
>               << " as an std::int64_t\n";
> }
> ```
>
> ouput
>
> ```
> o
> n
> c
> e
> 0x1.999999999999ap-4 is 3fb999999999999a as an std::int64_t
> ```

---

As long as the asserts pass (your are writing and reading the correct number of bytes) then the operation is safe.  You can't pack a 64 bit object in a 32 bit object, but you can pack one 32 bit object into another 32 bit object, as long they are [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable)

Comment: I prefer `std::copy` but yeah

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I don't beleive that's 100% portable.  While a good implementation will use `memcpy`/`memmove`, it's not required and the naive implementation would truncate.

Comment: Not sure I follow - implementation notwithstanding, the semantics differ only in typesafety, I thought?

Comment: `std::copy(static_cast<unsigned char*>(&d), static_cast<unsigned char*>(&d) + sizeof(d), static_cast<unsigned char*>(&n))` (my goal literally being just to force people to spell out the type to avoid surprises)

Comment: Oh.  I keep forgetting you can cast.  nvm me

Comment: Hehe. Now that I've written it out, it looks pretty horrid and verbose, but I split it over lines or wrap it in something, so... I just don't like `memcpy`'s `void*` is all. I realise I'm just kinda reinventing that erasure :P

Answer (score -3):

Or this:

```
union TheUnion {
    uint32 theInt;
    float theFloat;
};

TheUnion converter;

converter.theFloat = myFloatValue;
uint32 myIntRep = converter.theInt;
```

I don't know if this is better, but it's a different way to look at it.

Comment: In C++ it is this is UB.

Comment: This approach is found in a lot of places (as is the approach of a pointer cast) but unfortunately it is not okay.

Comment: Why is it not okay?

Comment: The standard explicitly forbids it.  When you access the non active member of a union it is put in indeterminate state.  Accessing something in an indeterminate state is undefined behavior.  More than likely it will "do the right thing", but you have no guarantee.